# Display data from mysql query in table format php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have the following problem. When I do a query to my database (MySql) I get the following table:

```
City    Elm     Serial  Amount

Paris   Car     123     1
Paris   Car     124     4
Paris   Car     125     2
Paris   Bus     321     1
Paris   Taxi    457     3
Dublin  Car     478     2
Dublin  Car     614     5
Dublin  Bus     982     2
Madrid  Car     637     3
Madrid  Bus     186     2
Madrid  Taxi    612     7
Madrid  Taxi    785     3
```

What I want to do with this data is display it in these format:

```
Paris   

Car 

123 1
124 4
125 2

Bus 

321 1

Taxi    

457 3



Dublin  

Car 

478 2
614 5

Bus 

982 2



Madrid  

Car 

637 3

Bus 

186 2

Taxi    

612 7
785 3
```

I am going totally crazy trying to set up multidimensional arrays and if clauses and can't figure out how to do it.

Any ideas on how can I achieve these reseult ?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Maybe show us how far you've got by yourself, so we can work from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data_array = array();
while ($record = db_fetch_array($your_result_set)) {
    $data_array[$record['City']][$record['Elm']][$record['Serial']] = $record['Amount'];
}
```

I think that should fill your array

```
foreach ($data_array as $city=>$values) {
    echo "$city\n\n";
    foreach ($values as $elm=>$subvalues) {
        echo "$elm\n\n";
        foreach ($subvalues as $id=>$amount) {
            echo $id." ".$amount."\n";
        }
    }
}
```

And the output

Comment: BRILLIANT !!! Thank you SOOOO much for your help. I would show what I was up to with my array, but posting that "monster" after seeing your simple and clean solution makes me feel a bit (well, more than a bit) ashame. I am HAPYYYYYYY